# How to select an image url using cheerio and axios

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

```
const express = require("express");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require("axios");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

async function getSearchResults(searchFor) {
    const url = `https://www.bol.com/be/nl/s/?searchtext=airpods+pro`;
    const respone = await axios.get(url);
    const $=cheerio.load(respone.data);

    // verwreken van het resultaat in een array
    const ul = $('.product-list');
    ul.find('li .product-item__image .h-o-hidden a .skeleton-image').each((i, element) => {
        const $element = $(element);
        const a = $element.find('img').attr('src');
        console.log(a);   
    });
}
```

[I also give the HTML of the website I'm trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqbeu.png)
So far it recognizes that there are indeed ~20 pictures but it gives an undifined value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the first img inside this div does not have a `src` attribute.

Here is the working code:

```js
const ul = $('.product-list');
ul.find('li .product-item__image .h-o-hidden a .skeleton-image')
  .each((i, element) => {
    const $element = $(element);
    const a = $element.find('img').attr('data-src');
    console.log(a);   
 });
```

[proof of work screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEW0K.png)

Comment: the attr should be 'data-src' now it's working thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reference the actual image tag, which is another level down.

Try the following:

```js
ul.find('li .product-item__image .h-o-hidden a .skeleton-image').each((i, element) => {
const $element = $(element);
        const a = $element.find('.skeleton-image__container').find('img').attr('src');
    });
```

Or, if there's only one div under `skeleton-image` class:

```js
ul.find('li .product-item__image .h-o-hidden a .skeleton-image').each((i, element) => {
const $element = $(element);
        const a = $element.find('div').find('img').attr('src');
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No cause I'm doing that already bellow:
`const a = $element.find('img').attr('src');`
But thank you for your time!

Comment: I think the problem is caused by the image being nested between another element under `skeleton-image`. I have edited my answer slightly. Let me know if that is more similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey Aastha unfortunately it's still not working. Do you feel comfortable doing a zoom meeting? Maybe if we look at it together, we might find a solution?